# Difference between the % position in mysql like command

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

what is the difference between the below like commands in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE filedname LIKE '12%';
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE filedname LIKE '%12';
```

Comment: In simple words 12% means select filedname starting with 12    and     %12  select filedname ending with 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent is a wildcard that will match anything. So '12%' will match '12abc', but it won't match 'abc12'. While '%12' will do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

in

> SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE filedname LIKE '12%';

you'r searcing a filedname value that start with 12 
like : "12whatever"
and in

> SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE filedname LIKE '%12';

you'r searcing a filedname value that end with 12 
like : "what ever 12"

Answer (score 0):

The % symbol means that anything can be in that side and it will match.

For example with '12%' would match '12345' or '12 dogs', or with '%12' would match '2012' or 'I am 12'.

Answer (score 0):

When `LIKE` is used along with `%` sign then it will work like a meta character search.
The percent sign wildcard can be used to represent any number of characters in a value match.

for example to list all the rows where the product name ends in the words 'Computer Case':

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_name LIKE '% Computer Case';
+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+
| prod_code | prod_name          | prod_desc         |
+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+
|        11 | Grey Computer Case | ATX PC CASE       |
|        12 | Gray Computer Case | ATX PC CASE (USA) |
+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Alternatively, the wildcard could be placed at the end of a value, for example to retrieve all the items in stock manufactured by the fictitious WildTech Corporation:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_name LIKE 'WildTech%';
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
| prod_code | prod_name                | prod_desc              |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|         3 | WildTech 250Gb 1700      | SATA Disk Drive        |
|        13 | WildTech Mouse (Optical) | Wireless Optical Mouse |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```